# Summarizing a table result in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given the below table as a SQL Result:

[image: Current Result]

I want to use the above generated table and produce a table which clubs the given information into:

[image: Required Result]

I have multiple areaName and multiple functionNames and multiple users. Please let me know if this is possible and how?

I have tried couple of things but I am just drained out now and need a direction. Any help is appreciated.

Even if you can provide a pseudo code, I can try and make use of it. Start from the SQL result as a given table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `correlated sub-queries` to achieve the desired result. I've provided an example below. Test it for the first summary column, and then add in your other summary columns if it does. Hopefully this makes sense, and helps. Alternatively you could use a [CTE (common table expression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to achieve similar results.

```
SELECT a.areaName, a.functionName
       , (SELECT count(DISTINCT b.UserKey) 
             from AREAS b 
             where a.areaName = b.areaName 
             and a.functionName = b.functionName 
             and b.[1-add] = 1) as UsersinAdd
-- Lather/rinse/repeat for other summary columns

FROM AREAS a
group by a.areaName, a.functionName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the de-normalised structure of your table. Columns `[1-add],...,[8-correction]` should be values in a column, not columns. This leads to more complex queries, as you have discovered.

The `unpivot` command allows you to correct this mistake.

```
select areaname, functionname, rights, count(distinct userkey)
    from 
    (
    select * from yourtable
        unpivot (permission for rights in ([1-add], [2-update/display],[4-update/display all] , [8-correction] )) u
    ) v
    group by areaname, functionname, rights
```